# Recursive search in python

Tags: python, numpy, recursion

I am trying to implement a search algorithm in such a scenario:
Assume there are 5 people: people # 0-4, people only know who directly works under them. For example, people 0 and 1 manage no one, people 2 manages people 0, people 3 manages people 1, while people 4 manages both people 2 and 3.

[image: The described hierarchy]

Assume I store this hierarchy in a list called hierarchy`hierarchy = [[],[],[0],[1],[2,3]]`

What I am trying to find is who works directly and indirectly under an arbitrary person, In this case, people who work directly and indirectly under 4 should be 0,1,2,3, or `[0,1,2,3] = allUnder(hierarchy,ID = 4)`.

I think the solution to the question is some kind of recursive search, but I am quite fuzzy about recursion. The algorithm I am looking for should also be efficient in case of duplicate values (e.g. assume 3 manages both 0,1, the answer should still be 0,1,2,3).

I know I am supposed to put my solution first, but I really don't know how to solve it at this point... Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Update: I am also very interested in finding all direct and indirect manegement of a particular person.

Comment: Would something like `np.unique(list)` accomplish what you need?

Comment: You may want to look into using an adjacency list, and then implementing an algorithm like depth first search or breadth first search.

Comment: What you are trying to do is called a [Tree Traversal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal). [See if this link helps](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/tree-traversals-inorder-preorder-and-postorder/).

Comment: @RoryDaulton I have edited the post and put the data structure back in, I have also updated the post to show that I want to get people working under an arbitrary people rather than the top management,

Comment: @tel yes... I want to search up the hierarchy as well, I didn’t think much about this when I start the question , now I realize it’s an interesting compliment of the question as well.

Comment: @Susie I update my answer to include bottom-up searching, via the `getparents` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Solution

Given that you want two-way search (ie to be able to search for both subordinates and managers), you'll want some kind of tree structure that encodes two-way links between its nodes. Here's a class that implements such a tree:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, val):
        """initialize a node with the worker id value
        """
        self._children = []
        self._parent = None
        self.val = val

    def link(self, *node):
        """create a parent-child link between this (parent) node and one
        or more (children) nodes
        """
        for n in node:
            n._parent = self
            self._children.append(n)

    def get(self):
        """depth-first recursive get
        """
        return [x for y in ([n.val] + n.get() for n in self._children) for x in y]

    def getparents(self):
        """walks up parents (currently there's at most one parent per-node)
        """
        return [] if self._parent is None else [self._parent.val] + self._parent.getparents()

class Tree:
    def __init__(self, idlists):
        """initialize the tree as per the OP's example input
        """
        self._nodes = {}
        for topid,idlist in enumerate(idlists):
            self.add(topid, idlist)

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self._nodes[key]

    def _getnode(self, i):
        """get or create the node with id=i.
        Avoid constructing new Nodes if we don't have to 
        """
        if i in self._nodes:
            return self._nodes[i]
        else:
            n = self._nodes[i] = Node(i)
            return n

    def add(self, topid, idlist):
        """create a node with id=topid (if needed), then add
        child nodes, one per entry in idlist
        """
        self._getnode(topid).link(*(self._getnode(i) for i in idlist))
```

## Testing it out

Here's how to use the above defined `Tree` class to solve your specified problem:

```
data = [[],[],[0],[1],[2,3]]
people = Tree(data)

## get subordinates

print(people[4].get())
# output: [2, 0, 3, 1]
print(people[2].get())
# output: [0]
print(people[1].get())
# output: []

## get managers

print(people[1].getparents())
# output: [3, 4]
print(people[2].getparents())
# output: [4]
print(people[4].getparents())
# output: []
```

## Ramble

This is a classic CS chestnut that doesn't seem to get much exposure in modern coding tutorials (I think because many of the problems that used to be solved with trees now have simpler hash table/dict based answers).

Comment: You should include a way to generate the linked list from the input defined by OP: `[[],[],[0],[1],[2,3]]` otherwise your solution is kind of off topic.

Comment: I also don't think your data structure actually qualifies as a singly linked list, since you have more than one node connection per node. This is a tree.

Comment: Good point about the singly linked list. I was abusing the terminology a bit (the structure I was describing isn't really any kind of linked list). I changed my answer to match. The OP's input data structure is kind of non-standard/awkward, so I don't think focusing on the exact form of it is that important (though I updated my answer to match that too)

Answer (score 1):

Represent this problem as a directed graph using adjacency list like data-structure. And going with your assumption, 3 manages 0 and 1.

graph = { 4 : [2, 3], 2 : [0], 3 : [0, 1] }

Use Depth-First-Search (DFS) or Breath-First-Search (BFS) traversal to list people who report under a person.

DFS(graph[2]) should return 0

DFS(graph[4]) should return 0, 2, 1, 3

BFS(graph[4]) should return 2, 3, 0, 1

Comment: That's... not very specific. Maybe also include a Python implementation, like the OP asked for?

Answer (score 1):

If we assume a top down hierarchy, this is sufficient:

```
people = [[],[],[0],[1],[2,3]]

def manages(manager, people):
  lst = people[manager]
  for employee in lst:
    lst = lst + manages(employee, people)
  return lst

print(set(manages(4, people)))
```

Outputs: `{0, 1, 2, 3}`

Here's a working [example](https://repl.it/repls/WateryGenuineSearchservice).

This solution will not terminate if there are circular relationships in the input list.

Answer (score 0):

I'm imagining the hierarchy as a dictionary:

```
hierarchy = { 4: { 2: 0, 3: 1 } }
```

Where I can define a recursive method tho get the children:

```
def get_all_children(father, res=None):
  if res == None: res = []
  res.extend(father.keys())
  for child in father.values():
    if not isinstance(child, dict):
      res.append(child)
    else: get_all_children(child, res)
  return res
```

Then I can call:

```
print(get_all_children(hierarchy[4]))
#=> [2, 3, 0, 1]
```

---

Also

```
hierarchy = {5: { 4: {2: 0, 3: 1} }, 8: {7: 6} }
print(get_all_children(hierarchy[5]))
#=> [4, 2, 3, 0, 1]
```